# Displaying 5 top scores from txt file java

Tags: java

I've made a card game, similar to solitaire. It's almost finished. The last thing I'm struggling with is printing top 5 scores. Whenever player ends a game it writes into scores.txt file how many piles he's left on a table, let's say 4. So in the .txt file I have following numbers: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`. How can I print from file top 5 of these, so it's: `1,2,3,4,5`.

```
DeckOfCards class:
import java.io.*;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DeckOfCards {
private ArrayList<Cards> deck;
private int currentCard=-1; //index of the next card to be dealt
private Scanner in;
private int i;
//ArrayList<Integer> indexesToRemove = new ArrayList();
/**
 *
 * Constructor to build a deck of cards
 */

public DeckOfCards() {
    this.deck = new ArrayList<Cards>();
}

public void removeCard(int i) {
    this.deck.remove(i);
}
public Cards getCard(int i){
    return this.deck.get(i);
}
public void addCard(Cards addCards){
    this.deck.add(addCards);
}

//Draws from the deck1
public void draw(DeckOfCards comingFrom){
    currentCard++;
    this.deck.add(comingFrom.getCard(0));
    comingFrom.removeCard(0);
}
public void saveScore(){
    try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("scores.txt"))) {
        out.print(deck.size());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Card class:

```
public class Cards {
private String suit;
private String value;


public Cards(String suit, String value)
{
  this.suit = suit;
  this.value = value;
}

public String getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public void setSuit(String suit) {
    this.suit = suit;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return suit + value;
}
}
```

Hope it helps. I got rid of some methods I believe they aren't useful. There's also the menu and like I said every case works except of displaying top 10 results.
1 - Print the pack out (this is so you can check that it plays properly)
2 - Shuffle
3 - Deal a card
4 - Make a move, move last pile onto previous one
5 - Make a move, move last pile back over two piles
6 - Amalgamate piles in the middle (by giving their numbers)
7 - Print the displayed cards on the command line
8 - Play for me once (if two possible moves, makes the ‘furthest’ move)
9 - Play for me many times
10 - Display top 10 results

Comment: This is a little too vague. Please include some code and explain what specifically you're stuck on.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code you have written? (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: edited. sorry for vague, believed it was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

When the game is over, read the input file in memory (like in a list), add the new result at the position it should go in the leaderboard, write the new results in the file, then take the five first of the list (element 0 is best score and element n is worst score).

```
public void endGame(int finalScore) throws IOException {
    List<String> scores = retrieveScores();
    addNewScore(finalScore, scores);
    writeScores(scores);
    showLeaderBoard(scores);
}

private List<String> retrieveScores() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("score.txt"));
    String scoreLine = reader.readLine(); // read line that contains scores
    List<String> scores = new ArrayList<>();
    if (scoreLine != null) { // in case of first game
        String[] tempScore = scoreLine.split(", ");
        scores = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(tempScore));
    }
    reader.close();
    return scores;
}

private void addNewScore(int finalScore, List<String> scores) {
    boolean foundSpotForNewScore = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (!foundSpotForNewScore && i < scores.size()) {
        if (finalScore <= Integer.parseInt(scores.get(i))) {
            foundSpotForNewScore = true;
        } 
        i++;
    }
    scores.add(i, String.valueOf(finalScore));
}

private void writeScores(List<String> scores) throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("score.txt");
    String outputScores = scores.toString();
    outputScores = outputScores.replace("[", "");
    outputScores = outputScores.replace("]", "");
    writer.write(outputScores);
    writer.close();
}

private void showLeaderBoard(List<String> scores) {
    System.out.println("*** TOP 5 LEADERBOARD ***");
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 5 && i < scores.size()) {
        System.out.println(scores.get(i));
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("*** TOP 5 LEADERBOARD ***");
}
```

Comment: added some code, hope it helps. the thing is I don't know at which position it should go. I had an idea with inputting this into an ArrayList as well, so I'll probably do that, but in this case do you know how to print top 10(so 10 smallest numbers) from ArrayList. I guess I'll use Collections.min(list), but it works just for one number. Any ideas?

Comment: First, make a function retrieveScores(). That return a List by reading the first line of the file and by using split(","). Next add the result to the list at the good location (if you always add at the good location, score will always be good to bad). After this, write the List in file by using toString() on list and by removing "[" and "[" with replace("[", ""). Finally, get the first five or 10 first elements of the list because they are the best score due to the fact that your list is always in the good order.

Comment: I edited the answer with some code to help you to understand what i meant.